# Umbraco 5 - passing data from controller to view

Tags: model-view-controller, umbraco

I have been playing around with Umbraco 5 for some days now. I have made a partial view with some dummy-text that I have inserted into a page template. Work's fine. The problem is when I have to pass data from a controller to the view.

The view inherit from RenderViewPage (`@inherits RenderViewPage`) as default in Umbraco 5. I tried to do it the regular MVC way by `@model ViewPage<Umbraco.Cms.Web.UI.Models.Test>` but I got an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should start by creating a Surface controller (can be done in seperate project or create controller folder directly in main project):

```
public class ContactFormSurfaceController : SurfaceController
{
    [ChildActionOnly]
    public PartialViewResult ContactForm()
    {
        var model = new ContactViewModel();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
}
```

Don't inherit form RenderViewPage just strongly type your view with your own model
Then create a macro that call the ChildAction ContactForm
You can add your action through editor or via code in templates: @Umbraco.RenderMacro("ContactForm")